# Flutter Circle Design

Tags: dart, flutter

[image]

I want to make this kind of design with these white circles as a raised button.

Comment: You can use [CustomMultiChildLayout](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html) to draw this kind of layouts. Here you can find a tutorial:
[How to Create Custom Layout Widgets in Flutter](https://www.sayonetech.com/blog/how-create-custom-layout-widgets-flutter/).

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Try This!

[image: demo]

I have added 5 circles you can add more. And instead of **RaisedButton** use **InkResponse**.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new ExampleWidget()));
}

class ExampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget bigCircle = new Container(
      width: 300.0,
      height: 300.0,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.orange,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
    );

    return new Material(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: new Center(
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            bigCircle,
            new Positioned(
              child: new CircleButton(onTap: () => print("Cool"), iconData: Icons.favorite_border),
              top: 10.0,
              left: 130.0,
            ),
            new Positioned(
              child: new CircleButton(onTap: () => print("Cool"), iconData: Icons.timer),
              top: 120.0,
              left: 10.0,
            ),
            new Positioned(
              child: new CircleButton(onTap: () => print("Cool"), iconData: Icons.place),
              top: 120.0,
              right: 10.0,
            ),
            new Positioned(
              child: new CircleButton(onTap: () => print("Cool"), iconData: Icons.local_pizza),
              top: 240.0,
              left: 130.0,
            ),
            new Positioned(
              child: new CircleButton(onTap: () => print("Cool"), iconData: Icons.satellite),
              top: 120.0,
              left: 130.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CircleButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final GestureTapCallback onTap;
  final IconData iconData;

  const CircleButton({Key key, this.onTap, this.iconData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double size = 50.0;

    return new InkResponse(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: new Container(
        width: size,
        height: size,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: new Icon(
          iconData,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ajay Kumar, I tried this it is really awesome. Can you help me to make it relative or % based, as I want this to be displayed same on different size devices and on the web as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 113):

you can use decoration like this :

```
   Container(
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                    child: Icon(CustomIcons.option, size: 20,),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Color(0xFFe0f2f1)),
                  )
```

Now you have circle shape and Icon on it.

[image]

Comment: The secret is in width & height, otherwise `shape: BoxShape.circle` will not work properly.

Comment: Wrapping this with `ClipRRect` with `BodderRadius.circular(30)` (half of the container width)  will also hide the elements outside the circle.

Answer (score 34):

### More efficient way

I recommend drawing a circle with **CustomPainter**. It's very easy and way more efficient than creating a bunch of widgets/masks:

[image: Flutter draw circle]

```dart
/// Draws a circle if placed into a square widget.
/// https://stackoverflow.com/a/61246388/1321917
class CirclePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final _paint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.red
    ..strokeWidth = 2
    // Use [PaintingStyle.fill] if you want the circle to be filled.
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawOval(
      Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
      _paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Usage:

```dart
  Widget _buildCircle(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      size: Size(20, 20),
      painter: CirclePainter(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I get Stackoverflow in this.

Comment: Custom Paint take a lot of resources to build so its better to avoid it when possible. @Sana ebadi answer is the best for this situation.

Answer (score 29):

I would use a https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html to be able to freely position widgets.

To create circles

```
  new BoxDecoration(
    color: effectiveBackgroundColor,
    image: backgroundImage != null
      ? new DecorationImage(image: backgroundImage, fit: BoxFit.cover)
      : null,
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
  ),
```

and https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.rotate.html to position the white dots.

Comment: As a newbie, I need more than references to two pages in flutter.io texts. I need a more extensive example. Can you provide your answer to OP's question as a complete example or provide a reference to such an example. Because I plan to use transforms in my application, I am very interested in the Stack class. However, I don't have a clue how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: Very helpful answer. Thanks @Gunter!

Comment: It's impossible to animate this by using `AnimatedSwitcher`

Answer (score 0):

May be not the most suitable but very concise solution to create a filled circle:

```
CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: _getColor())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This!

[image: Output]

### Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: CircleDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class CircleDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const CircleDemo({super.key});

  @override
  _CircleDemoState createState() => _CircleDemoState();
}

class _CircleDemoState extends State<CircleDemo> {
  final List<int> circlesCount = [
    12,
    6,
  ];
  final double mainRadius = 100.0;
  final double inRadius = 18.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 300.0,
          height: 300.0,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: mainRadius * 2,
                  height: mainRadius * 2,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    radius: inRadius,
                  )),
                ),
              ),
              for (int i = 0; i < circlesCount.length; i++)
                ...List.generate(
                  circlesCount[i],
                  (index) {
                    double angle =
                        ((index + 1) * (math.pi * 2)) / circlesCount[i];
                    double radius = (mainRadius / (i + 1)) * 0.8;
                    double x = radius * math.cos(angle) + mainRadius;
                    double y = radius * math.sin(angle) + mainRadius;
                    return Positioned(
                      left: x + (32),
                      top: y + (32),
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                        radius: inRadius,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```