# How to draw a simple circle in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Most of the tutorials I found on drawing circles on flutter were related to buttons. What if I simply want to draw a circle?

One way would be with `ClipOval`:

```
ClipOval(child: Container(color: Colors.grey,width: 15, height: 15),)
```

What if I want to draw borders and so? `ClipOval` does not seem to be the best way to do it.

Comment: just give it a search!! https://stackoverflow.com/a/61246388/12341099

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use a container

```
Container( 
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
    ),
    ...
),
```

Supports borders:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html