# How I can create multiple circle avatar UI like below in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to create multi-circle avatar UI like this.

[image: Expected output]

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50522237/flutter-circle-design

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Circle Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50522237/flutter-circle-design)

Comment: Do you want them to be interactive/animated as well in some way?